# Templates while exporting Jupyter notebook to PDF with nbconvert

Tags: python, templates, jupyter-notebook

Someone knows how to use templates while exporting Jupyter notebook to PDF with nbconvert? Where did I get templates?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A few built-in [formats](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/external_exporters.html) are available by default: html, pdf, webpdf, script, latex

You can use the below code to export your code to a pdf:

```py
$ jupyter nbconvert --to FORMAT notebook.ipynb
```

This generates notebook.ipynb, with the FORMAT you want.

Also, you can also extract the code from a notebook into an executable script, i.e., for an iPython notebook extract the Python code cells into a Python script:

```py
$ jupyter nbconvert --to script my_notebook.ipynb
```